# Stripe::InvalidRequestError: You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm building an ecommerce using ruby on rails and while trying to integrate stripe I get the following error:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError in CheckoutController#create
You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or 
`line_items.images` in this API version. 
Please use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`. 
Please see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices for more information.
```

My CheckoutController looks as following:

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController

  def create
    order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    prices = order.articles.map do |article|
      { price: article.stripe_pricing_id, quantity: 1, description: article.title }
    end

    session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      cancel_url: order_url(order),
      success_url: root_url,
      mode: 'payment',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: prices
    })

    redirect_to session.url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `description` field is not available for `line_items` in the API version you are using. This should work if you initialize `prices` like so by discarding description:

```rb
prices = order.articles.map do |article|
  { price: article.stripe_pricing_id, quantity: 1 }
end
```

If you want to include `description` field, then you need to use `price_data` as mentioned in their docs here. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices#server-side-code-for-inline-items